# Redux Thunk return dispatch not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

using Redux Thunk, first log 'OK' is OK, but process doesn't go to second console.log.

Anyone knows what's wrong?
Thank you

```
export const postTweet = (body) => {
  console.log('OK')
  return dispatch => {
    console.log('NO LOG')
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added redux-thunk middleware?

Comment: yes!! 

same issue with something like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698595/react-redux-thunk-actions-does-not-return-dispatch

Comment: should return in return dispatch?

Comment: can you paste the code where you dispatch `postTweet`

Comment: @OSAMAH I got it thanks to your asking.!! I didn't dispatch(postTweet), just  had called postTweet.

Answer (score 6):

You should do `dispatch(postTweet(body))`. just calling `postTweet` like postTweet(body) from component doesn't the trick.

Comment: Was stuck on this for an hour, this helped. Thank you!